# If hashcode of two String literal and string object is same in java then if they compared by == .Then find false.Why?

Tags: java, string

In below code HashCode of s1 and s3 are equal but s1==s3 returns false why?.Please clarify it.
Here s1 ,s2 and s3 contains same content and HashCode .
When run below code then out is

108274800

108274800

108274800

s1==s2

s1.equals(s2)

s1.equals(s3)

Code is given as follows...

public class StringTest {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

String s1="rahul";
String s2="rahul";
String s3=new String("rahul");
System.out.println(s1.hashCode());
System.out.println(s2.hashCode());
System.out.println(s3.hashCode());

if(s1==s2){

    System.out.println("s1==s2");
}

if(s1==s3){

    System.out.println("s1==s3");
}

if(s1.equals(s2)){

    System.out.println("s1.equals(s2)");
}

if(s1.equals(s3)){

    System.out.println("s1.equals(s3)");
}

}
```

}

Comment: Because it's a new string object, and `==` compares references.

Comment: Asked like a zillion times before, man.

Comment: Just an addition, hash contract says if two object are equal, have to have same hash, but hash can be the same also for two strings which are not equal...

Answer (score 1):

== Compares only the reference type, to compare objects or string, you should must use `s1.equals(s2)`

Comment: I read this line on SO, about 1000 times ;)

Comment: And you may also want, he will read that minimum 1 time.

Comment: what is relation between hashcode and ==.This is my question ?Please suggest on this basis.

Comment: If strings are equal then their hash codes must also be equal.  The reverse is not true.  Different strings may have identical hash codes.  The number of possible strings is vastly greater than the number of possible hash codes, so duplicate hash codes are inevitable.